# Using SASS variables in Rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I am afraid that this question is simply stupid, but... is there any option to use SASS variables in rails `.erb` files?

I defined a few colors in my `variables.css.scss` and I wish to use their values in my views or helpers in Rails. Maybe Rails can see some compiled sass resources or something?

Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it the other way around, ie using ruby code in your css/sccs code. It's a bit tricky, but it may help you :

First declare the color as a ruby constant :

```ruby
# Put this into config/initializers/constants.rb for example
module Constants
  FOO_COLOR = '#123456'
end
```

Next, rename the `variables.css.scss` into `variables.css.scss.erb` and use the constant created at the previous step

```scss
$fooColor: <%= Constants::FOO_COLOR %>
```

Finally use the color in your other scss files

```css
@import "_variables";
#foo {
    background-color: $fooColor;
}
```

And you can also use the `Constants::FOO_COLOR` in your Rails code too.

Be careful, you may be using precompiled assets in production. It will work with a constant as shown below, but it won't work if you want to change the value, or get it from a DB.

Comment: Don't forget the line-ending `;` in the now templatized scss file ;-)